# My android app is not compatible on some new devices

Tags: android

I got my first app published a few hours ago.
But I have a problem.
My app is compatible for the majority of the phones but there are some recent phones for which my application is not compatible.
I don't understand, I use the 28 version of SDK.
I can't find a cause.
For example, my application is compatible for Samsung Galaxy S10e but not for S10.

I can't find where the problem is.

Here is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nicolanovic.wallpapers"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />

    <compatible-screens>

        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />

        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />

        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />

        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />


    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />

</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: why do you need all those screen sizes in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Because your screen list is not exhaustive

From the android doc:

> If your application is compatible with only small and normal screens, regardless of screen density, then you must specify twelve different  elements, because each screen size has six different density configurations. You must declare each one of these; any combination of size and density that you do not specify is considered a screen configuration with which your application is not compatible. Here's what the manifest entry looks like if your application is compatible with only small and normal screens:

```
<manifest ... >
...
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
<application ... >
    ...
<application>
```

Also it doesn't make much sense to use these filters, android layouts adapts pretty well even for 8 inch tablets

from the doc:

> Caution: Normally, you should not use this manifest element